# Joining record to get most recent

Tags: mysql

I have tables:

users

```
id | first_name | last_name
 1   Johnny       Steve
 2   Kim          Borden
```

sales

```
id | user_id | service_id | date
 1    1         2           2012-02-12
 2    1         6           2012-04-21
```

I would like to retrieve the list of users with their recent sales information attached. NULL's if nothing found.

What I have so far:

```
SELECT
    users.*,
    sales.*,
FROM
    users
LEFT JOIN
    sales ON users.id=sales.user_id
```

But this creates two records for Johnny because of the two in sales. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you only looking up one user at a time, or trying to get the most recent sales record for all users?

Comment: I am looking to get a list of all users in the table with extra columns having the sales information of the most recent sale.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT u.id as id, u.first_name as first_name, u.last_name as last_name, MAX(s.date) as `date`
FROM users as u LEFT JOIN sales as s on u.id = s.user_id
GROUP BY id

Check out this links for more complex top N per group type of query structures.

http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Comment: how do I get the latest service_id?

Comment: Is is something that is absolutely required?  As doing so will make query much more complex if you need to get all user data with a single query.

Comment: Yeah I need all columns in sales, which are more than service_id.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
        u.*,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(s.id ORDER BY s.date DESC,s.id DESC),',',1) as sale_id,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(s.service_id ORDER BY s.date DESC,s.id DESC),',',1) as service_id,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(s.date ORDER BY s.date DESC,s.id DESC),',',1) as sale_date
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN sales s ON s.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id;
```

this is the closest you can get to 'last sale' without having the time

Comment: just because autoincrement id is higher, does not mean the date is most recent. But you would need to self-join the sales table to itself in a subquery to get the most recent date for each user.

Comment: @MikeBrant date column values don't include time, so this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT u.*, s.*,
    FROM users u
    LEFT JOIN 
(select max(id) as sales_id, user_id from sales group by user_id) sa 
on sa.user_id = u.id
    LEFT JOIN sales s ON sa.user_id=s.user_id and s.id=sa.sales_id
```

EDIT: if you make date a TIMESTAMP you can use it instead of id in MAX(). If you keep it as date, you can still use it, however you will get extra records in case there were more than one sale for user in one day

Answer (score 0):

Without the use of analytic functions, this is a pretty basic way to do what you're trying to do:

```
select users.*, sales.*
from users, 
(select a.*
    from sales a,
        (select user_id, MAX(date) as mostRecentDate
        from sales
        group by user_id) b
    where a.user_id = b.user_id
      and a.date = b.mostRecentDate) sales
where users.id = sales.user_id;
```

I don't have a mysql server available to me at the moment to test this, if it gives any errors, just post back.

Comment: By looking at your other comments, this query is likely to solve your problem.  I only worry about the alias on the sales subquery, but that should be easy to fix.

This should give you all columns in sales and users.